# Does python logging replace print?

Tags: python, logging

Up to now, I've been [peppering my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116543/how-to-replace-print-debug-message-with-the-logging-module) with '`if VERBOSE: print debug message`'. Then I learned how to use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. It looks as though it does everything I could possibly want, and then some. So much so that I got carried away and replaced *all* `print` statements in my code with `logging` statements, not just the verbose ones.

Is this a mistake? If I'm already using `logging`, can I use it to replace `print` in every way? If not, how do I choose whether to use `logging` or `print`?

Answer (score 8):

`print` would still be used for output that is essential to the operation of your program. `logging` is for output that might be useful in determining how your program is working (errors, progress, etc), but could be omitted without affecting the usability of your program.

The [Basic Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial) discusses when to use `logging` versus other mechanisms.

Comment: Link to the same tutorial for Python 3 - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Answer (score 3):

Some people say that logging is for *operators* of your software.  That means, people who need to correct a recurring error, or tell what is the state of a running software while it runs.

One could then say that printing is for *users* of your software. That means, those people who are interested in the results of running your software.  If there is an error, they are not able to correct it, so they can only ignore it, or stop using your software altogether.

That is why, traditionally, logging goes to `stderr`, while printing goes to `stdout`.

So, logging **should not** completely replace printing, because each is intended for a different audience.  You **can** misuse it to completely replace printing (e.g. by using different handlers that attach to `stderr` and `stdout` with different levels), but this is misusing the logging system in the same way that before you were misusing the printing statements to do logging.

Incidentally, misusing `print` statements for debugging is sometimes called [Caveman logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189639/2250036).  Welcome outside the cave! :)

Answer (score 1):

Python logging can completely replace your print statements. You just have more options.
The default configuration of logging writes to the console as print does, but you can use logging in other ways, like writing to a logging server, reformatting the output, adding information like the module the line came from, or the time.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to consider is if you have code where speed is a concern.  Or if you are printing something where formats may change in rare corner cases, like say if communication is lost, or an error occurs.

Consider these 2 options:

```
msg = "Parameters are: %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f"%(p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7])
logger.debug(msg)
```

or

```
if VERBOSE:
    msg = "Parameters are: %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f"%(p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7])
    print msg
```

In the first case, the string formatting is still getting done even if the logging level is not DEBUG, which will impact overall performance.  In the second, if VERBOSE is False, nothing gets done.

Also, I have ran into troubles where exceptions are generated from the string formatting of debug messages.  Take for example in the above code, if there is a rare use case where "p" only has 6 values, you will get an index error.  Or if one of the p values is "None", you will get an exception.  But in the second case, if VERBOSE is False, you will never see a crash caused by the debug code.

So logging is very handy, but I tend to use it only in cases where I want the messaging as a permanent code feature.  If I need to put in a temporary message to help debug a one time problem, I'll usually just use print statements.

And also as general rule, stuff the end user is meant to see should be "print".

Answer (score 0):

`logging` may or may not completely replace your `print()` calls. In some cases, like when developing a library or using multiple threads logging is the better choice.

There are no hard rules about it. Personally I tend not to mix logging and print and use either the one or the other.